# Recover from Exceptions in callProcess

Tags: haskell, exception, conduit

In my following code, I use callProcess to run external `git pull`. What I want is that if `git pull` fails in one directory, the program will skip it and try the next directory. But with my code, the program stops with the error messages from git:

**Error message:**

> We are at:/home/nut/dev/haskell/haskellnews You are not currently on a
>   branch. Please specify which branch you want to merge with. See
>   git-pull(1) for details.
>
> ```
> git pull <remote> <branch>
> ```
>
> scripts-exe: callProcess: git "pull" (exit 1): failed

**My code:**

```
src = sourceDirectory "/home/haskell" `catchC` (\(e :: MyException)-> liftIO $ throwIO $ MyException (show e))

    .| C.mapM_ (\f ->
              do
                 b <- liftIO . doesDirectoryExist $ f
                 case b of
                   True -> do liftIO . setCurrentDirectory $ f
                              bb <- liftIO . doesDirectoryExist $ ".git"
                              case bb of
                                True -> liftIO $ do
                                  res <- try (callProcess "git" ["pull"]) :: IO (Either MyException ())
                                  case res of
                                                    Right a -> putStrLn "we are good"
                                                    Left e -> putStrLn "bad git"
                                False -> liftIO . putStrLn $ "Not a git directory"
                   False -> do liftIO . putStrLn $ "Not a directory"
             )

main :: IO ()
main = runConduitRes $ src
```

Comment: `callProcess` throws an exception if the exitcode is non-zero. Either use a different function that returns the exit code and handle it yourself, or catch the error.

Comment: Just found out that I should have used `SomeException` instead of `MyException`

Comment: I'd recommend reading [the documentation for safe-exceptions](https://haskell-lang.org/library/safe-exceptions) and [typed-process](https://haskell-lang.org/library/typed-process), which may help explain how to do these kinds of things.